# How to set mask for CPF or CNPJ with MaskedInput from ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner with ReactJS and I'm trying to set up a mask for the input field of my form.

This mask that I'm trying to configure must be dynamic, because it should work if the field is CPF or CPNJ:

**CPF format:** `111.111.111-11`

**CNPJ format:** `11.111.111/1111-11`

**Regex to validate both:** `/(^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\-\d{2}$)|(^\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}\-\d{2}$)/`

I am using `react-text-mask` to try to configure the mask. I am inserting the CPF and CNPJ regex but the `react-text-mask` does not recognize it. When the user types more than 11 characters automatically, the mask is in the CNPJ format. Can you tell me how I can do that?

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-bash-0k75u?file=/src/App.js)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply format the data in the input event using the `onChange` property of the **TextField** component and then remove the `InputProps` property and the **TextMaskCustom** component.

```js
const handleCpfCnpjChange = (event) => {
  // Get only the numbers from the data input
  let data = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
  // Checking data length to define if it is cpf or cnpj
  if (data.length > 11) {
    // It's cnpj
    let cnpj = `${data.substr(0, 2)}.${data.substr(2,3)}.${data.substr(5,3)}/`;
    if (data.length > 12)
      cnpj += `${data.substr(8, 4)}-${data.substr(12, 2)}`;
    else 
      cnpj += data.substr(8);
    // Pass formatting for the data
    data = cnpj;
  } else {
    // It's cpf
    let cpf = "";
    let parts = Math.ceil(data.length / 3);
    for (let i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
      if (i === 3) {
        cpf += `-${data.substr(i * 3)}`;
        break;
      }
      cpf += `${i !== 0 ? "." : ""}${data.substr(i * 3, 3)}`;
    }
    // Pass formatting for the data
    data = cpf;
  }
  // Update state
  setcpfCnpjValue(data);
};
```

Complete code here: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-ishizaka-cffk4?file=/src/App.js)